# Best way to store state in an apache camel context

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I need to persist a single string value which changes hourly and is fetched by a route for other routes to use. I'm using the Spring XML DSL.

I've got it working fine, but it seems clumsy. I have a java class with a setter and a getter to wrap the string and I set it with:

```
<to uri="bean:store?method=setValue"/>
```

And get it back into the body in another route with:

```
<to uri="bean:store?method=getValue"/>
```

Is there a pure Spring way of doing this in the xml without needing a bespoke java class?

Comment: This is trivial when using Java DSL since you can just refer to some value container object, when using XML DSL I think there is now other way around that. You can use `camel:setProperty` to set property on exchange, but for the routes in question that might not apply if they don't share exchange. So I am afraid there is no better way in XML DSL.

Comment: Thanks @hgrey. At least that's two of us think that way.

Comment: Not a spring person myself but why don't you store it in a camel cache and do lookup when you need the value?

Comment: Because I hadn't spotted it. Thanks, I'm going to check your blog out too.

Comment: Cool, glad to help. Like Raul mentions, it is relatively easy to use the Cache for basic state lookup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several options:

1. Use a cache component such as Apache Ignite, EhCache, etc. Although this is **overkill** for such a simple scenario as yours. I don't recommend it.
2. Use a JDK [`AtomicReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) as your bean, rather than creating a dedicated class just for storage.

   - Invoke the [`set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html#set(V)) method to store a value.
   - Invoke the [`get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html#get()) to recover the value.

Obviously you won't get rid of the steps in the route to store/fetch the value, but you can scrap away your custom class.

Comment: Thanks raulk, both exactly the kind of suggestion I wanted. I hadn't spotted either the AtomicReference class (or its generic version) or camel:cache. I'll use one where I don't need distributed replication across camel instances and the other when I do.

Comment: You may also want to think about persistence across restarts and downtime. Although by your description, it sounds like another system is already responsible for the durability of the datum, right?

Comment: Thanks raulk. In this case I don't need to persist across restarts.  I have others where I do and I'm comfortable with how to do those. It was this trivial case I was sure there must be a better solution for. Thanks for the great suggestions.